# Post two similar columns nodejs mysql using postman

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I have a question how do I post two similar columns, I tried sending it with array using for of cause I'm using async/await and when I only post one column it works perfectly, but it doesn't when it has two similar columns, any information would really help me

here are my models

```
postItems: function (setData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.query('INSERT INTO datas (picture, name, price, quantity, delivery_on, data_description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [setData.picture, setData.name, setData.price, setData.quantity, setData.delivery_on, setData.data_description], function (err, res) {
        if (!err) {
          resolve(res)
        } else {
          reject(err)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

```
postItemsToItemCategory: function (setData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.query('INSERT INTO data_categories ( data_id, category_id) VALUES (?, ?)', [setData.data_id, setData.category_id], function (err, res) {
        if (!err) {
          resolve(res)
        } else {
          reject(err)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

and here's my controller

```
postItemData: async function (req, res) {
    const setData = req.body
    try {
      if (setData.price < 1) {
        return helper.response(res, 'fail', 'Cannot type number below 1', 400)
      }
      const result = await itemModels.postItems(setData)
      const categoryData = {
        data_id: result.insertId,
        category_id: setData.category_id
      }
      if (typeof categoryData.category_id !== 'object') {
        categoryData.category_id = [categoryData.category_id]
      }
      for (const category of [categoryData]) {
        try {
          console.log(categoryData)
          await postItemsToItemCategory(category)
          console.log(`product ${result.insertId} has been created on category ${setData.category_id}!`)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      }
      return helper.response(res, 'success', result, 200)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return helper.response(res, 'fail', 'Internal Server Error!', 500)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code, so if anyone needs it maybe it will help

```
//model
postItemsToItemCategory: function (setData, cb) {
      db.query('INSERT INTO data_categories ( data_id, category_id) VALUES (?, ?)', [setData.data_id, setData.category_id], cb)
  }
```

and I found the problem I'm not careful to not put the await and change the for of into forEach

```
postItemData: async function (req, res) {
    const setData = req.body
    try {
      if (setData.price < 1) {
        return helper.response(res, 'fail', 'Cannot type number below 1', 400)
      }
      const result = await itemModels.postItems(setData)
      if (typeof setData.category_id !== 'object') {
        setData.category_id = [setData.category_id]
      }
      await setData.category_id.forEach((categoryId) => {
        const categoryData = {
          data_id: result.insertId,
          category_id: categoryId
        }
        postItemsToItemCategory(categoryData, () => {
          console.log(`product ${result.insertId} has been created on category ${categoryId}!`)
        })
      })
      return helper.response(res, 'success', result, 200)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return helper.response(res, 'fail', 'Internal Server Error!', 500)
    }
  }
```